# Copy filtered range from main sheet to specific columns in another google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically I want to filter this sheet
by column J "company" and copy paste to several sheets.

[Data Sheet][image: 1]

For example, the script will filter by Column J - KMA and it will populate into this Testing sheet 1 - KMA
[Testing Sheet 1][image: 2]

Then the script will filter by Column J - LOL and it will populate into this Testing Sheet 2 - LOL

[Testing Sheet 2][image: 3]

Whenever I populate the testing sheets, it will key in the current date in column A.

I tried using this code and it works. But they are not appending to a new empty row.... and it loads pretty slow

```
    function FilterByKMA() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var test1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Sheet").getSheetByName("Sheet"); // Actual Sheet
  const  range = ss.getRange("A:X");
  var checkfilter = range.getFilter();
    const filter = range.createFilter();
    const Filter_Criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(["KMA"]);
    const coll1 = 10; //
    const add_filter = filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(coll1,Filter_Criteria);
    Logger.log("Filter has been added.");

    for(var i = 2; i <= ss.getLastRow();i++){
        if(ss.getRange(i,10).getDisplayValue()=="KMA")

        {
            var tid = ss.getRange(i,1).getDisplayValue();
    console.log(tid)
            var last_scan_type = ss.getRange(i,6).getDisplayValue();
            var last_scan_date = ss.getRange(i,7).getDisplayValue();
            var last_scan_name = ss.getRange(i,9).getDisplayValue();
            var maincon = ss.getRange(i,10).getDisplayValue();
//    var to = ss.getRange(i,).getDisplayValue();
            var cxname = ss.getRange(i,14).getDisplayValue();
            var cxcontact = ss.getRange(i,15).getDisplayValue();
            var to_address = ss.getRange(i,13).getDisplayValue();
            var cod_cost = ss.getRange(i,17).getDisplayValue();
            var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
            var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    test1.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "dd-MMM-yyyy"),email,,tid,,,,,,to_address,cxname,cxcontact,,,,last_scan_type,last_scan_date,last_scan_name,cod_cost])

    }
    }

    filter.remove();
    
}
```

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**plain text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to the question. Adding such "markdown tables" greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Could you share the sample sheets that you are working on? Always try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)